# Replacement of nested repeater in MVC 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want a replacement of nested repeater in MVC 4.0.
Actually, my scenario is something like:

- I have a table "tbl_class" which contains contains records of all the classes(id, class, floor)
- I have another table "tbl_students" which contains records of all the student(id, 
  fName,lName,rollNo,Class....etc).
- I want to show records of all the student class wise.

### Class I floor 0

```
student1 
student2 
student3 
student4
```

### Class II floor 0

```
student5
student6
student7
student8
.
.
.
.
.
```

Can anybody suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is no repeater(server side controls) in mvc ,in mvc you can only use `html` tags or `htmlhelpers` ,for your requirement you can make a **model class with required lists** and then use **foreach loop** in view for example :-

```
@foreach(var item in Model.itemlist)
{ .... }
```

OR

You can use `@Html.EditorFor()` or `DisplayFor` with an Editor/Display Template.

Comment: Ok, fine. Please read my scenario and suggest me the best solution.

Comment: @AshishVerma..plz read the answer carefully i have written solution for your scenario there in answer itself.

Comment: It is giving the following error at list type property:         must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern. Automatically implemented properties must define both get and set accessors